# How to substitute a sequence of the same character and of variable length in bash?

Tags: bash, sed, substitution

I am quite sure this question already have an answer, but i can't find it so if there is one, please link it in the comments.

Otherwise, the problem i need to solve is how to substitute a sequence of the same character, that may occur once or more and we don't know how many times at max, with a single character, in order to organise strings with a known delimiter.

Also, in my specific case i have to substitute the `*` but i can do a preprocessing to substitute it with an easier-to-handle character.

This is a quite bad solution and it assumes that the max length of the pattern is known. But, of course, this is not true.

`cat example_file.txt | sed 's/\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/_/g' | sed 's/\*\*\*\*\*\*\*/_/g' | sed 's/\*\*\*\*\*\*/_/g' | sed 's/\*\*\*\*\*/_/g' | sed 's/\*\*\*\*/_/g' | sed 's/\*\*\*/_/g' | sed 's/\*\*/_/g' | sed 's/\*/_/g' > clean_file.txt`

with `example_file.txt` containing something like:

```
>SH1111056.09FU|KC881085_refs|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Sordariomycetes;o__Hypocreales;f__Clavicipitaceae;g__Neotyphodium;s__Neotyphodium_siegelii;|foliar_endophyte*litter_saprotroph*class1_clavicipitaceous_endophyte**leaf/fruit/seed**non-aquatic*arthropod-associated*filamentous_mycelium******
>SH1115797.09FU|UDB031565_refs|k__Fungi;p__Basidiomycota;c__Agaricomycetes;o__Hymenochaetales;f__Hymenochaetaceae;g__Fomitiporia;s__Fomitiporia_hippophaeicola;|plant_pathogen*wood_saprotroph**wood_pathogen*wood*white_rot*non-aquatic**filamentous_mycelium*polyporoid*poroid****
>SH0879139.09FU|KF945456|k__Viridiplantae;p__Anthophyta;c__Eudicotyledonae;o__Lamiales;f__Acanthaceae;g__Ruellia;s__Ruellia_brandbergensis;|ND**************
>SH0991532.09FU|UDB07658019|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Venturiales;f__Venturiaceae;g__Sympodiella;s__Sympodiella_sp;|litter_saprotroph****leaf/fruit/seed**non-aquatic**filamentous_mycelium******
>SH0991546.09FU|UDB07657573|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Venturiales;f__Venturiaceae;g__Sympodiella;s__Sympodiella_sp;|litter_saprotroph****leaf/fruit/seed**non-aquatic**filamentous_mycelium******
```

EDIT:

the expected output, assuming the `*` is substituted with `_` would be this:

```
>SH1111056.09FU|KC881085_refs|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Sordariomycetes;o__Hypocreales;f__Clavicipitaceae;g__Neotyphodium;s__Neotyphodium_siegelii;|foliar_endophyte_litter_saprotroph_class1_clavicipitaceous_endophyte_leaf/fruit/seed_non-aquatic_arthropod-associated_filamentous_mycelium_
>SH1115797.09FU|UDB031565_refs|k__Fungi;p__Basidiomycota;c__Agaricomycetes;o__Hymenochaetales;f__Hymenochaetaceae;g__Fomitiporia;s__Fomitiporia_hippophaeicola;|plant_pathogen_wood_saprotroph_wood_pathogen_wood_white_rot_non-aquatic_filamentous_mycelium_polyporoid_poroid_
>SH0879139.09FU|KF945456|k__Viridiplantae;p__Anthophyta;c__Eudicotyledonae;o__Lamiales;f__Acanthaceae;g__Ruellia;s__Ruellia_brandbergensis;|ND_
>SH0991532.09FU|UDB07658019|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Venturiales;f__Venturiaceae;g__Sympodiella;s__Sympodiella_sp;|litter_saprotroph_leaf/fruit/seed_non-aquatic_filamentous_mycelium_
>SH0991546.09FU|UDB07657573|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Dothideomycetes;o__Venturiales;f__Venturiaceae;g__Sympodiella;s__Sympodiella_sp;|litter_saprotroph_leaf/fruit/seed_non-aquatic_filamentous_mycelium_
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: is this what you want ? `cat example_file.txt | tr -s '*' '_' > clean_file.txt` if yes I put it as your answer !

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i'll add an example, one sec!

Comment: @Freeman i think that is the solution. let me have a better look!

Comment: @Freeman yes, i just looked `man tr` and the `-s` does what i was looking for. go ahead with the answer ;-)

Comment: @Freeman `cat` is useless here and in most cases, `cat` is useless. `tr -s \* _ < example_file.txt > clean_file.txt` would do it.

Comment: @Freeman Rule-of-thumb: if you can put `cat` before a pipe `|` like `cat something |` then replace it with `< something`

Comment: @LéaGris yes thnx, in most cases, it is recommended to use "<" instead of "cat" before a pipe "|". It helps to improve the efficiency and readability of the command!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this out

```
tr -s '*' '_' < example_file.txt > clean_file.txt
```

or

```
cat example_file.txt | tr -s '*' '_' > clean_file.txt
```

the output

```
>SH1111056.09FU|KC881085_refs|k_Fungi;p_Ascomycota;c_Sordariomycetes;o_Hypocreales;f_Clavicipitaceae;g_Neotyphodium;s_Neotyphodium_siegelii;|foliar_endophyte_litter_saprotroph_class1_clavicipitaceous_endophyte_leaf/fruit/seed_non-aquatic_arthropod-associated_filamentous_mycelium_
>SH1115797.09FU|UDB031565_refs|k_Fungi;p_Basidiomycota;c_Agaricomycetes;o_Hymenochaetales;f_Hymenochaetaceae;g_Fomitiporia;s_Fomitiporia_hippophaeicola;|plant_pathogen_wood_saprotroph_wood_pathogen_wood_white_rot_non-aquatic_filamentous_mycelium_polyporoid_poroid_
>SH0879139.09FU|KF945456|k_Viridiplantae;p_Anthophyta;c_Eudicotyledonae;o_Lamiales;f_Acanthaceae;g_Ruellia;s_Ruellia_brandbergensis;|ND_
>SH0991532.09FU|UDB07658019|k_Fungi;p_Ascomycota;c_Dothideomycetes;o_Venturiales;f_Venturiaceae;g_Sympodiella;s_Sympodiella_sp;|litter_saprotroph_leaf/fruit/seed_non-aquatic_filamentous_mycelium_
>SH0991546.09FU|UDB07657573|k_Fungi;p_Ascomycota;c_Dothideomycetes;o_Venturiales;f_Venturiaceae;g_Sympodiella;s_Sympodiella_sp;|litter_saprotroph_leaf/fruit/seed_non-aquatic_filamentous_mycelium_
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are misusing `sed` 's' mode which accept regexp:

```
sed -E -e 's/\*+/_/g' example_file.txt > clean_file.txt
```

The `+` being one or more of what's before (`*` in this case).

Comment: i didn't know how to allow for multiple matches with `sed` but thanks for the alternative solution!